# My old Android 7 phone can't connect to my Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I've an old Android 7 phone that can connect to my home WiFi just fine, on 2.4 GHz and on 5 GHz. But if I start an hotspot on my Pixel 7, the old phone can't connect to it... But if I try to connect to my hotspot with another phone, it's working fine, so it's not the hotspot...

The old phone can see the network, but it alternate between connecting and saved... It can't connect...

I've tried to activate Extend compatibility, it doesn't change anything.

Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score -1):

On Android 7 you may try changing the wifi encryption from WEP to WPA if available, which is supported by newer Pixel phones. WEP was found to have weakness and that's why newer phones like Pixel7 come with WPA encryption.

Comment: Hi. OP mentioned that their Android 7 device does not connect to the hotspot created by Pixel 7. A client device cannot change encryption setting of a Wifi outside of its control. Only the Access Point device can (which is Pixel 7 in this case). So changing hotspot's encryption setting on Android 7 is not something OP can do. Second, it is not established so far that OP's Android 7 device is incapable of connecting to a Wifi with WPA encryption.